# How to write php using style:""

Tags: php, css, image

I want to write php in a style tag but I dont know how. Now I am stuck with this :

```
echo"<div class='fill' style='background-image:url('upload/".$row['file1']."');'></div>";
```

But in the browser it shows like this :

```
<div class="fill" style="background-image:url(" upload="" test.png');'=""></div>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `'` as both the delimiter around the `style` attribute's value and around the URL inside the parentheses. The second `'` is ending the value. URLs inside a `url(...)` style don't need to be quoted, so you can just write:

```
echo "<div class='fill' style='background-image:url(upload/".$row['file1'].");'></div>";
```

Comment: `URLs inside a url(...) style don't need to be quoted` only if there's no white-space in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with PHP.

You have an HTML attribute value that you are delimiting with `'` characters.

You are trying to use a `'` inside it as data.

It terminates the attribute value instead of representing a quote mark.

Replace it with a character reference: `&#039;`

Answer (score 0):

swap your `'` with your `"`, or you can escape your quotes

```
echo '<div class="fill" style="background-image:url(upload/' . $row['file1'] . ');"></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use backslash to escape quotes

```
echo"<div class='fill' style='background-image:url(\'upload/".$row['file1']."\');'></div>";
```